# Image field file upload issue

Tags: files, paragraphs

I'm using Drupal 8 and paragraphs together, and I've got an image field attached to an image paragraph. When adding content, if I nest this inside of another paragraph (as a paragraph reference field), the file upload fails. I get the throbber gif, and then "No file chosen." If I use this paragraph type without nesting it, it works fine.

Logs and watchdog show no errors, and all other file related things (logo's, other image and file fields) work properly on their own (verified it's not a permissions or other related issue).

Answer (score 2):

Spent some time looking around for an answer to this, so I thought I'd write it up even though I figured it out.

The combination of machine names involved in my nesting for the paragraph type and the paragraph reference field were overloading the ajax link length. I shortened the paragraph reference field machine name and nesting now works beautifully!